# How to reduce sway on this ikea console table

Tags: woodworking, table

This tall ikea table is 74” long and I use it primarily as a kitchen counter/workspace. Unfortunately it sways a bit when I apply weight or pressure longways. Any suggestions for how I can brace or reinforce this to reduce the sway?

[image: Ikea condole table]

Comment: Double check that all fasteners are still tight. Especially if it's more wobbly now than it was when you first built it.

Comment: Definately check all the hardward, we had this exact table years ago, though we painted it black. Was never swaying for us. Something is likely loose somewhere. Regardless couple of thin metal staps cross crossed may help

Answer (score 1):

Triangulation is <s>thought of</s> as the strongest configuration. That would mean the drawers would only be accessible from one side, if the diagonal straps reached the top. So you could use one strap or two, spreading from the bottom of one leg to just under the drawer on the opposite leg. Doing the same, but the opposing way on the other side would make it doubly strong, and would make access a little awkward to the shelves, so maybe try one side first.

Strap? A strip of matching wood would do the job - after all the strip is in tension. But maybe an aluminium strip would look better.

Comment: "Triangulation is _thought of_ as the strongest configuration"? Triangulation _is_ the strongest configuration. That's why large towers are built with triangular sections, steel roof girders are triangulated, etc. This is absolutely the right way to go. After, of course, ensuring that all the fasteners have been retightened.

Comment: Assessible from one side with this is not an issue, it has discs on the back of the draws to prevent them pushing out the back. Straps probably the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that when you assembled this you did a good job of tightening everything ?

It looks like those 2 shelves are loose and are just sitting on the supports ? If so, it would help to put a couple of 2" or 2.5" wood screws at the end of each shelf down into each of the cross pieces that go between the legs. With a solid attachment of those 2 shelves it should be pretty sturdy. Unfortunately, the joinery connections are typically not so good on these DIY assembly items.

Comment: It was definitely tightened when assembled 12 years ago and I think possibly less sway back then too. Now I’m concerned about over tightening to fix what I assume is sway due to age/settling/west on the joints

Answer (score 0):

As well as the points in the other answer:

Make some triangular brackets (4 or 5 inches on the side) and brace the corners - screwed and glued would be good.

Suggested that size so as to not interfere with access, classic bracing with diagonals from bottom corner to top would be very effective but would mess up access.